# Writing dplyr function to pass to group_map

Tags: r, dplyr

The problem in question would be to apply the function f to each group of a tibble. It is a simpler way to do this, but I would like to solve the problem using the `group_map()` function.

**Data used**: starwars of the **dplyr** package.

What I want is to get an average of the **height** variable for a grouped tibble considering the variables **gender** and **species**. I know the problem could be easily solved by doing:

```
starwars %>% group_by(gender, species) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE))
```

However, my desire is to implement `summarise(mean = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE))` in a function and send to `group_map()`.

I tried to create the `f()` function that gets the `data` argument which is a tibble object with the previously defined groups. The second argument of the `f()` function would be `...` so that I could pass the variables of interest from `data` to `f()`.

```
f <- function(dados, ...){
  dados %>% summarise(mean = mean(..., na.rm = TRUE))
}

starwars %>% group_by(gender, species) %>% 
  group_map(.tbl = ., .f = ~f(dados = .x), height)
```

Comment: You need to use tidyeval in your function. See [the vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) on it

Comment: Using `...` in your example implies that you want to get means of multiple columns. Is that the case, or do you want to just pass in one column to get the mean of?

Comment: Hi Camile, thanks for the info. tidyeval serves me but I'll think how to do for multiple variables. It can be a good exercise.

Comment: See [Chapter 8 of the Tidy Evaluation book](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html). It is very close to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solutions**:

```
func_1 <- function(dados, var, ...){

  var_interesse <- enquo(var)
  dots <- enquos(...)

  # Could be attributed direct reference ...
  dados %>% group_by(!!!dots) %>% 
    summarise(media = mean(x = !!var_interesse, na.rm = TRUE))
}

starwars %>% func_1(var = height, gender, species)
```

or

```
func_2 <- function(dados, var){

  var_interesse <- enquo(var)
  #dots <- enquos(...)

  dados %>%  summarise(media = mean(x = !!var_interesse, na.rm = TRUE))
}

agrupamento <- starwars %>% group_by(gender, species)

agrupamento %>% 
  group_map(.tbl = ., .f = ~func_2(dados = .x, var = height))
```